# OpenCV DescriptorMatcher radiusMatch and knnMatch result format

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

Does anyone happen to know why the OpenCV 2 `DescriptorMatcher::radiusMatch()` and `knnMatch()` take a `vector<vector<DMatch>>& matches`? I'm a bit confused about why it wouldn't just a vector, since it's just a single array of points in the scene that correspond to the training image, right?

I've got something like this:

```
void getMatchingPoints(
    const vector<vector<cv::DMatch> >& matches,
    const vector<cv::KeyPoint>& keyPtsTemplates,
    const vector<cv::KeyPoint>& keyPtsScene,
    vector<Vec2f>& ptsTemplate,
    vector<Vec2f>& ptsScene
    )
{
    ptsTemplate.clear();
    ptsScene.clear();

    for (size_t k = 0; k < matches.size(); k++)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < matches[k].size(); i++)
        {
            const cv::DMatch& match = matches[k][i];
            ptsScene.push_back(fromOcv(keyPtsScene[match.queryIdx].pt));
            ptsTemplate.push_back(fromOcv(keyPtsTemplates[match.trainIdx].pt));
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm a bit confused about how to actually map the approx. location of the object once I have them all in `ptsScene`. The points seem scattered to me when I just draw them, so I think I'm missing what the nested vectors represent.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `knnMatch` function will return the `k` nearest-neighbour matches, i.e. if you call `knnMatch(queryDescriptors, trainDescriptors, matchesQueryToTrain, 3)` where in this case `k=3`, then for each training point, it will find the 3 best matches from the query set.

In terms of your `vector<vector<DMatch>>`, this means that the outer `vector` is a vector of each query->train match, and the inner `vector` is a vector of your `k` nearest matches.

There is quite a good example of how to use these `k` matches along with a cross-checking method in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5937264/769220) other question.

If you want a simple 1-1 matching, then you can call knnMatch with k=1 which will return an inner vector of size 1, or just call `match` which outputs matches in the form `vector<DMatch>` with no second vector.